# How to refactor this double forLoop with lodash?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, refactoring, lodash

I have `selectedTags` which holds up to 3 tags.
`vm.tags` Could contain thousands, most likely just hundreds of tags that I need to compare too.

If the ids of the 3 tags match the id of a tag inside of `vm.tags` I need to turn their borders on. There are 3 borders too: `border1`, `border2`, `border3`.

```
const tagsColorCheck = () => {
    let name, selected, its_ticker;
    let selectedTags = TagsFactory.retrieveTickerTags('onlyTags');

    if (selectedTags.length > 0) {
        for (let i=0; i<vm.tags.length; i++) {
            for (let j=0; j<selectedTags.length; j++) {
                if (selectedTags[j].term_id == vm.tags[i].term_id) {
                    name       = 'border'+ ( j + 1 );
                    selected   = 'selected';
                    its_ticker = 'its_ticker';

                    vm.tags[i][name]     = true;
                    vm.tags[i][selected] = true;
                    vm.tags[i][its_ticker] = selectedTags[j].its_ticker;
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

So far here is what I have in process (`_.each`):

```
const tagsColorCheck = () => {
    let name, selected, its_ticker, vmTerm, term_1, term_2, term_3, ticker_1, ticker_2, ticker_3;
    let selectedTags = TagsFactory.retrieveTickerTags('onlyTags');

    if (!_.isEmpty(selectedTags)) {
        vmTerm = R.findIndex(R.propEq('term_id', selectedTags[0].term_id))(vm.tags);
    }

    if (selectedTags[0]) { term_1 = parseInt(selectedTags[0].term_id); ticker_1 = selectedTags[0].its_ticker; }
    if (selectedTags[1]) { term_2 = parseInt(selectedTags[1].term_id); ticker_2 = selectedTags[1].its_ticker; }
    if (selectedTags[2]) { term_3 = parseInt(selectedTags[2].term_id); ticker_3 = selectedTags[2].its_ticker; }

    _.each(vm.tags, (tag) => {
        if (tag.term_id === term_1) {
            tag.selected = true;
            tag.border1  = true;
            tag.its_ticker = ticker_1;
        }

        if (tag.term_id === term_2) {
            tag.selected = true;
            tag.border2  = true;
            tag.its_ticker = ticker_2;
        }

        if (tag.term_id === term_3) {
            tag.selected = true;
            tag.border3  = true;
            tag.its_ticker = ticker_3;
        }
    })
};
```

And this (`for of loop`):

```
const tagsColorCheck = () => {
    let name, selected, its_ticker, vmTerm, term_1, term_2, term_3, ticker_1, ticker_2, ticker_3;
    let selectedTags = TagsFactory.retrieveTickerTags('onlyTags');

    const borderRizeTag = (tag) => {
        if (tag.term_id === term_1) {
            tag.selected = true;
            tag.border1  = true;
            tag.its_ticker = ticker_1;
        }

        if (tag.term_id === term_2) {
            tag.selected = true;
            tag.border2  = true;
            tag.its_ticker = ticker_2;
        }

        if (tag.term_id === term_3) {
            tag.selected = true;
            tag.border3  = true;
            tag.its_ticker = ticker_3;
        }
        return tag;
    }

    if (!_.isEmpty(selectedTags)) {
        vmTerm = R.findIndex(R.propEq('term_id', selectedTags[0].term_id))(vm.tags);
    }

    if (selectedTags[0]) { term_1 = parseInt(selectedTags[0].term_id); ticker_1 = selectedTags[0].its_ticker; }
    if (selectedTags[1]) { term_2 = parseInt(selectedTags[1].term_id); ticker_2 = selectedTags[1].its_ticker; }
    if (selectedTags[2]) { term_3 = parseInt(selectedTags[2].term_id); ticker_3 = selectedTags[2].its_ticker; }

    for (let tag of vm.tags) {
        console.log(tag);
        tag = borderRizeTag(tag);
    }

    console.log('vmTerm',vmTerm);
};
```

Comment: It's working, it's easy to understand/maintain and it won't get any faster. So why would you want to convert it into a lodash version? O.o - Your lodash script is slightly confusing, fixed to three tags and not easy to extend. The vanilla version has this all for free.

Comment: I don't care about the speed actually, but readability. Functional programming... a for loop is hard to read, a double for loop is just diarrhea.

Comment: @LeonGaban As someone who programs in a functional language every day, and who cannot write for loops even if I wanted to (I don't), I will tell you that your double for loop is imminently more readable than your other versions.  I will compose an answer later, but don't accept with blind faith that "for loops are hard to read" as a general statement.  Often that is true, but in your case the for loops wins.  As Andreas said, your other versions are not extensible, and they're harder to reason about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ES6 fiddle to run:  http://www.es6fiddle.net/is0prsq9/ (note, copy the entire text, and paste it inside a browser console or a node REPL, and then examine the value of `tags` to see the result)

It's not lodash, and you don't really need it with ES6 constructs.  Relevant code:

```
const tagsColorCheck = () => {

  let tags = TagsFactory.retrieveTickerTags('onlyTags')

  sel.forEach( (s,i) =>
    tags.filter(t => t.term_id === s.term_id).forEach( t => {
      t['border' + (i+1)] = true
      t.selected = true
      t.its_ticker = s.its_ticker
    })
  )

  return tags
}
```

If you were writing this in a functional language, you would have access to a [list comprehension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_comprehension) and it would be a bit cleaner.  Essentially, this is a pretty clear case of `(for every x in a and y in b)` so a list comprehension is what you need, but you don't have it in javascript ([mozilla has it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Array_comprehensions), but not useful outside of that realm).

The result is a somewhat functional approach -- however, it can never really be functional in pure javascript.  Possibly the most important benefit of the functional paradigm are [immutable data structures](http://clojure.org/reference/data_structures) where you would compose your new list.  Instead, you just modify them in place here, which really is not very functional at all.  Still, if you prefer the `each` approach to a literal incremental one, as you have done above and as I did in my post, then it's a (albeit slower but arguably cleaner) better approach.

Comment: I think the line that sets the `name` is supposed to be `t['border' + (i+1)] = true,` Also, don't forget the commas inside the object.

Comment: @4castle - thanks for the correction on the property name.  the `t => {` portion is not generating a new object, so there are no commas to place.  This is simply the function body of the anonymous function.

Comment: Oh yes I see that now. Wasn't thinking there.

Answer (score 1):

Figured out an awesome solution! :D using both [_lodash](https://lodash.com/docs) and [ramda](http://ramdajs.com/0.21.0/docs/#equals).

So below, immediately `each` is quicker to reason about, then using `R.equals` to compare if the `term_ids` match. Then setting the values of the keys on the correct `tag` object.

```
if (!_.isEmpty(selectedTags)) {
    _.each(vm.tags, tag => {

        _.each(selectedTags, (selectedTag, index) => {
            let areTermIDsSame = R.equals;

            if (areTermIDsSame(parseInt(selectedTag.term_id), parseInt(tag.term_id))) {
                name       = 'border'+ ( index + 1 );
                selected   = 'selected';
                its_ticker = 'its_ticker';

                tag[name]       = true;
                tag[selected]   = true;
                tag[its_ticker] = selectedTag.its_ticker;
            }
        });
    })
}
```

Comment: I think you've missed the point of using lodash. Sure, it removes boilerplate `for` loop code, but otherwise it's the same imperative style code. Their desire was functional code, so I'm skeptical this is an improvement. Also, why not `===`?

Comment: Oh so I had a bug using `===` because one term_id was a string, the other was a number. So using `parseInt` now to make sure they are numbers in the `R.equals` function.

Comment: To be most efficient, you should store both an a number. Otherwise it has to parse at every iteration.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is simple - create an index of all tags by `term_id`. Iterate the selected tags. If a tag is found by id in the tags index, mutate it by assigning an object with the new properties.

btw - The only thing lodash is needed for is [`_.keyBy()`](https://lodash.com/docs#keyBy), and you can easily do that using `Array.prototype.reduce` if you don't want to use lodash.

```js
/** mocked vm **/

const vm = {
 tags: [{ term_id: 1 }, { term_id: 2 }, { term_id: 3 }, { term_id: 4 }, { term_id: 5 }, { term_id: 6 }]
}

/** mocked TagsFactory **/

const TagsFactory = {
 retrieveTickerTags: () => [{ term_id: 1, its_ticker: 'ticker 1' }, { term_id: 4, its_ticker: 'ticker 4' }, { term_id: 5, its_ticker: 'ticker 5' }]
};

const tagsColorCheck = () => {
  const selectedTags = TagsFactory.retrieveTickerTags('onlyTags');

  if (selectedTags.length === 0) { // if selectedTags is empty exit
    return;
  }

  const vmTagsIndex = _.keyBy(vm.tags, (tag) => tag.term_id); // create an index of tags by term_id

  selectedTags.forEach(({
    term_id, its_ticker
  }, index) => { // loop through selectd tags and retreive term_id and its_ticker from the current selected tag
    const tag = vmTagsIndex[term_id]; // find the tag in the vmTagsIndex

    if (!tag) { // if the id doesn't exist in vmTagsIndex exit
      return;
    }

    Object.assign(tag, { // mutate the tag by assigining it an object with the available properties
      selected: true,
      [`border${index + 1}`]: true,
      its_ticker
    });
  });
};

tagsColorCheck();

console.log(vm.tags);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.15.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
```